# Remove double quotes around string list

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I have a list with dates in it.

```
event_labels = []
for item in all_list:
    event_labels.append(str(item.event_created_at))

context['graph_data_labels'] = json.dumps(event_labels)


"['2018-05-18', '2018-05-17', '2018-05-16', '2018-05-15', '2018-05-14', '2018-05-13', '2018-05-12', '2018-05-11']"
```

I am using this data to output for labels in chartjs. Problem is the sourrounding double quotes around the event_labels list.

I have another list with just integers and it does not have the sourrounding quotes around the beginning and the end of the list.

```
[26.0, 50.0, 27.0, 87.0, 46.0, 24.0, 18.0, 34.0]
```

How do I output a string list without the double quotes at the beginning and end?

In the frontend HTML its like this:

```
<div>[26.0, 50.0, 27.0, 87.0, 46.0, 24.0, 18.0, 34.0]</div>

<div>"['2018-05-18', '2018-05-17', '2018-05-16', '2018-05-15', '2018-05-14', '2018-05-13', '2018-05-12', '2018-05-11']"</div>
```

Problem is in the console or if I just print it, I dont see the "

So the output that I want is:

```
<div>['2018-05-18', '2018-05-17', '2018-05-16', '2018-05-15', '2018-05-14', '2018-05-13', '2018-05-12', '2018-05-11']</div>
```

Comment: no need to use json dumps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json.dumps(event_labels)` convert list object to the string. So it's adding quotes in the template. You need to remove this line in the view and add to the context list directly:

```
event_labels = []
for item in all_list:
    event_labels.append(str(item.event_created_at))

context['graph_data_labels'] = event_labels
```

Also you can use `safe` template filter to disable escaping:

```
<div>{{graph_data_labels|safe}}</div>
```

Comment: Removed json.dumps. Still the same. It seems to only add " when the list is strings, its not added when its integers

Comment: @Sharpless512 probably you overrided later `graph_data_labels`. Can you post fill view code and related tempate part? Also try `<div>{{graph_data_labels|safe}}</div>` to render singlequotes in html without escaping.

Comment: <div>{{graph_data_labels|safe}}</div> worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use:-

```
stringVariable.strip('"')
```

Comment: It doesnt actually work since the object does not have " , only when I output it in the frontend

Comment: can you paste the code, which you use to print the output to html?

Comment: <div>{{graph_data_labels}}</div>

Comment: it's just a hack, but can help in short solution, use as:-
`event_labels_string = "['"+"','".join(event_lables)+"']"`